# linux - bsqldb login failed

Tags: linux, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 using the following command:

```
bsqldb -S something.example.com -D databasename
```

It returns this:

```
Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1
Server 'SOMETHING', Line 1
        Login failed for user ''.
bsqldb: Msg 20018, Level 5
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server.

bsqldb: Msg 20014, Level 9
Login incorrect.

bsqldb: bsqldb.c:169: main: Assertion `dbproc != ((void *)0)' failed.
Aborted
```

Is bsqldb not intended to connect to SQL Server 2008? How do I interpret this error message?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved for me when I mentioned the input file name correctly using the `-i` parameter.

The error message indicates that it did not find anything to execute but it does not clearly indicate what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's attempting to connect using Windows authentication, but can't. [According to the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bsqldb), you can also specify a SQL authentication username:

```
bsqldb -S something.example.com -D databasename -U username -P password
```

Comment: I don't have a username/password for this database. I've accessed this database before in python, it didn't require username/password. I used pyodbc on windows: `cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                      +"SERVER=something.example.com;"
                      +"DATABASE=databasename;")`. Any way to mirror that here with bsqldb?

Comment: I don't have any experience with `bsqldb`, I was merely going from their documentation. Did you try running the program as an administrator? Are you sure you are logged in as the same Windows user that you were logged in when you did this with python? You say it worked "before" - does it work in python now? Did anything change?

Comment: Thanks for wanting more detail. Doing a `sudo bsqldb -S something.example.com -D databasename` doesn't change the output - it still returns an error. Yes, I am logged on as the same user in linux as I was in windows. Yes, it works in python now, nothing has changed. I just can't get it to work in Bash using bsqldb. Also, for more information - I do have an example bash script where a bsqldb command is successful. It connects to different server than something.example.com, and it does use -U -P.

Comment: @Evan Sorry, I don't know, but clearly your domain username is not being passed along correctly. I don't know if that's a limitation in bsqldb or in how it's being called. Since you know -U -P works, have you considered trying SQL authentication?